# JDBC - Oracle - BatchUpdateException.getUpdateCounts() returns blank array

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am trying to execute the batch query using `PreparedStatement.executeBatch()` and trying to catch any exception occurred in `BatchUpdateException`. But I am getting a blank array on calling `BatchUpdateException.getUpdateCounts()`.

Below is my code:

```
int[] updateCounts = null;  
PreparedStatement stmt = null;  
// some logic to set the stmt and create the SQL query
try {  
if (count % 100 == 0)   
    {  
        updateCounts = stmt.executeBatch();  
     }  
} catch (BatchUpdateException bu)  
{   
        updateCounts = bu.getUpdateCounts();  
}
```

Here I get an empty array of `updateCounts` when an exception occurs... Why?

NOTE:

BatchUpdateException -

> SystemErr     R java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01400: cannot
>   insert NULL into ("TABLE_ABC"."AMOUNT")

CSV file from where the code reads the data... expecting error in the 3rd record

```
Asof_Date,Price_Date,Amount
12/15/2015,11/26/2014,-2646.937686
12/15/2015,11/28/2014,5053.611471
12/15/2015,1/22/2015,
12/15/2015,1/23/2015,
```

Comment: By empty array, do you mean an array with length = 0? If so, then it's likely because you didn't actually add anything to the batch, e.g. `count` is 0.

Comment: Well printing the exception might give some insight

Comment: @Andreas - it has 11 records i.e count is 11

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/BatchUpdateException.html), you get one int for the update count of **every successful executed statement** so an empty array suggests failure on first statement in batch.

> Retrieves the update count for each update statement in the batch update that executed successfully before this exception occurred.

As you are able to tell from your Exception,  empty values in your CSV cause the failure. So you either allow NULL for that column or check if null and insert 0 instead.

As for the updateCounts: if your batch ran in **one transaction** (which would make sense) then all inserts would be rolled nack on error - resulting in nothing done.

Comment: According to Javadoc... "a BatchUpdateException provides the update counts for all commands that were executed successfully during the batch update, that is, all commands that were executed before the error occurred", I don't even get that too

Comment: Print your exception with bu.printStackTrace () and post it into your question

Comment: Updated answer to reflect your new info.

Comment: Is there any way to do the batch insert/update and to know the individual query success or failure?

Comment: can you share the code (edit question) for the actual statement? How do you fill in values and so on?

Comment: (and upvoting would keep me motivated to help :-)